# Axon Distributed Command Bus+getting 404 while Posting the command

Tags: axon

I am using axon distributed command bus autoconfiguration using spring cloud and eureka
I observed all the required beans are getting created./member-capabilities is also exchanging the command information with other services and it is I can see this mapping exists in request mappings as well. Now when the command is being sent from another service by internally making a post-call to /spring-command-bus-connector/command endpoint
I am getting 404.[image]

[image]

I checked that SpringHttpCommandBusConnector's bean is loaded in application context
I tried adding a component scan as well
Also tried registering this mapping manually with dispatcher servlet still no luck

Comment: Hi Chetan! Can you update your questions with some more specifics of your project? Like the Axon Framework version, Axon Spring Cloud Extension version, Spring Cloud version, and the properties you're using? Furthermore, do you perhaps have some security set already? Lastly, I'd like to point you to the sample project Axon has for this, maybe that'll help: https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-springcloud-sample